# How would extraterrestrial organisms be categorized?

Tags: taxonomy

Suppose we find bacteria on Mars, we sequence its genome, and find it is genetically similar to $E. Coli$. Would we categorize it in the $Escherichia$ genus? Or would we put it into a seperate system of classification?

Comment: This question is indirectly about classification systems of biology. The main points in this question seem to be answered if we ask 2 questions. What happens if we find "life" that is not from the original cells that form our tree of life? Can and do we still base some of our trees of life on aesthetics alone?

Comment: @James that's put much more eloquently